# Boost::ASIO and std::packaged_task

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, variadic-templates

I have the following pieces of C++14 code

```
boost::asio::io_service service_;
```

I want to submit pieces of work into the `io_service`, using the following code that takes any function, it's input arguments and returns me a `std::future` to the return value.

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto enqueue(F &&f, Args &&... args) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type> {
  typedef typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type rType;
  auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<rType()>>(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f),
                                                                       std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  std::future<rType> res = task->get_future();
  service_.post(task);
  return res;
}
```

This was then called using

```
enqueue([] (int i) {
  return i+1;
}, 100);
```

This doesnt seem to be working. I get an error saying that `service_.post()` was not expecting this input.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:49:3:   required from ‘std::future<typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type> enqueue(F&&, Args&& ...) [with F = main()::<lambda()>::<lambda()>; Args = {int}; typename std::result_of<_Functor(_ArgTypes ...)>::type = int]’
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:44:6:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:102:3: error: static assertion failed: CompletionHandler type requirements not met
   BOOST_ASIO_COMPLETION_HANDLER_CHECK(CompletionHandler, handler) type_check;
   ^
/usr/include/boost/asio/impl/io_service.hpp:85:3: error: no match for call to ‘(std::shared_ptr<std::packaged_task<void()> >) ()’
   BOOST_ASIO_COMPLETION_HANDLER_CHECK(CompletionHandler, handler) type_check;
   ^
```

As far as I understand the `boost::asio` documentation, this can be done. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [`post()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/post.html):

> **handler**
>
> The handler to be called. The io_service will make a **copy** of the handler object as required. The function signature of the handler must be: `void handler();`

You are passing in a `std::shared_ptr<std::packaged_task<int()>>`. A `shared_ptr` doesn't have `operator()` defined. And `packaged_task` unwrapped isn't copyable.

So in order to make this work, you'll have to make a `shared_ptr<promise>`:

```
using R = std::result_of_t<F(Args&&...)>;
auto promise = std::make_shared<std::promise<R>>();
std::future<R> res = promise->get_future();

service.post([promise = std::move(promise),
    f = std::forward<F>(f),
    args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]{
        promise->set_value(std::experimental::apply(f, args));    
    });
return res;
```

Comment: Even if I call the `post()` function directly with the `std::packaged_task`, I get the same error... That is -- `auto task = std::packaged_task<rType()>(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));` and `service_.post(std::move(task));`

Comment: I guess the problem now is that the `operator()` has a non-`void` return type

Comment: @subzero `packaged_task::operator()` is definitely `void`, I'm wondering if there's something fishy with the concept check that they're doing (like it requires the type to be copyable somewhere).

Comment: Wrapping the task in a `void` return type lambda seems to work... `auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<rType()>>(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  std::future<rType> res = task->get_future();
  service_.post([=] () {
    task->operator()();
  });`

Comment: @subzero Updated my answer. I guess you could wrap a `shared_ptr<packaged_task>` too, but that seems unnecessary when you just need to wrap the promise.

Comment: Wow, "`io_service` will make a copy of the handler" -- I can't read.

Comment: Part of the reason for doing this was to allow for void functions to be passed in as well

Comment: @subzero Then yeah, lambda holding a  `shared_ptr<packaged_task<R()>>` is probably your best option.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember having been bitten by this myself. It's because `std::packaged_task` is not copyable (the copy constructor is explicitly deleted).

This is because it contains a promise, which is also not copyable - only moveable.

`asio::io_service` demands that handler objects are copyable.

You may want to consider building your own packaged-task-like function object which keeps a shared_ptr to the promise. That would be copyable.

The non-void return type is a red herring - don't waste your time with that.

documentation of packaged task here:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task

Answer (score 0):

With recent boost you can do this without a `shared_ptr` as follows.  You need two modifications:

1. use `boost::asio::post` instead of using the (deprecated) `post` function of the (deprecated) `io_service` or the newer `io_context`
2. the `packaged_task` needs to be wrapped in `std::bind` for reasons that I don't know.  Otherwise an exception is thrown at runtime.

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto enqueue(boost::asio::io_service& service_, F &&f, Args &&... args)
    -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type>
{
  typedef typename std::result_of<F(Args...)>::type rType;
  auto task = std::packaged_task<rType()>(std::bind(std::forward<F>(f),
     std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  std::future<rType> res = task.get_future();

  // Note the std::bind.  Without it the program would throw "future already received"
  boost::asio::post(service_.get_executor(), std::bind(std::move(task)));
  return res;
}
```

A self-contained example can be found here: https://godbolt.org/z/zE4qWbh1d